# If I add a row in Worksheet 1; First column should be transferred to Worksheet 2; rest of the row should be empty in Worksheet 2

Tags: excel, vba

Hopefully I can explain the issue well. If not, PLEASE ask, I will try to explain it as good as I can.

I have 2 different worksheets.
Scenario 1:
Sheet 1 has 2 columns and several rows.
Sheet 2 has the same data in the first column as Sheet 1 but the data of the other columns are different.

Change to Scenario 2: If I add a row in Sheet 1 the first cell of this row (“new”) should also be automatically added in Sheet 2. And in the second/third/… row of the second worksheet should be no data, as somebody has to fill it in manually.
Just the first column has to be the same in both worksheets. BUT the row has to be added in the second worksheet automatically also but without data.

[image: screenshot]

I really hope somebody can help me! Thanks so much in advance!

I tried it with macros and different formulas. But unfortunately I never got the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, using this macro (there might be some errors in it):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Column = 1 Then
    Sheets(2).Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = Target.Value
  End If
End Sub
```

For your information, this macro needs to "belong" to your first sheet:

[image]

Comment: Hello! Unfortunately it doesn't work :(  And I am not good enough with makros to find any mistakes.

Comment: It works when you add things at the end, not in the middle.